# Strange algebra among elliptic moments $k^pK^qK^\prime{}^r$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, contour-integration, elliptic-integrals

Let us define the complete elliptic integral of the first kind as follows:
$$
K(k)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k^2t^2}  } 
\text{d}t,
$$
where we restrict the modulus $k$ to $|k|<1$ with its complementary $K^\prime(k)=K\left ( \sqrt{1-k^2}  \right )$. They are shortened as $K,K^\prime$ respectively.
Now consider series of $M(p;q,r)=\int_{0}^{1}k^pK^qK^\prime{}^r\text{d}k$ where $p,q,r$ are natural numbers satisfying $p\le q+r-2$, denoting all the moments with $q+r=n$ as the set $I_n$. We have some facts:

1. $I_3\in\left \langle  M(0;3,0)\right \rangle _{\mathbb{Q}},I_5\in\left \langle  M(0;5,0),M(1;5,0)\right \rangle _{\mathbb{Q}}$. $\left \langle  \right \rangle _{\mathbb{Q}}$ means the corresponding $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space generated by the selected basis.
2. In $I_5$, virtually every element needs two coefficients except the trivial $(0;5,0)=(0;5,0),(1;5,0)=(1;5,0)$ and the remarkable $(0;2,3)=4(1;2,3)=4(1;3,2).$
3. For $I_7\in\left \langle M(0;7,0),M(1;7,0),\
   \Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{16}/\pi^4  \right \rangle_{\mathbb{Q}}$, we usually see four-term relations like $\int_{0}^{1}(1-k^2-4k^4)K^7\text{d}k= -\frac{63\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{16}}{491520\pi^4}$ but for (they are three-term relations)
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   &\int_{0}^{1}kK^3K^\prime\left ( K^3-kK^\prime{}^3 \right )
   \text{d} k = \frac{3\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{16} }{229376\pi^4},\\
   &\int_{0}^{1}k^3K^3K^\prime\left ( 3K^3-4kK^\prime{}^3 \right )
   \text{d} k = \frac{\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{16} }{28672\pi^4},\\
   &\int_{0}^{1}k^3K^5K^\prime\left ( 8K^\prime{}-k^2K \right )
   \text{d} k = \frac{\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{16} }{21504\pi^4},\\
   &\int_{0}^{1}k^3K^4K^\prime{}^2\left ( 15K^\prime{}-8kK \right )
   \text{d} k = \frac{\,\Gamma\left ( \frac14 \right )^{16} }{98304\pi^4}.
   \end{aligned}
   $$

To explore these relations, one can utilize the property $M\left ( p;q,r \right ) =\int_{0}^{1}k(1-k^2)^{(p-1)/2}K^rK^\prime{^q\text{d}k}$, quadratic transformations (i.e. substituting $k\rightarrow \frac{1-k}{1+k}$) and contour integration (considering functions like $k^pK^qK^\prime{}^r$). And here are my questions:

> How many irreducible moments in $I_{2n+1}$ for $n\ge1$? I conjecture it should be $n$.

> Do we have any tools to well describe these rational algebraic identities?

Comment: From which source, can I study these moments? Is there an online page?

Comment: @BobDobbs have a glimpse:http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1132